# android error cannot resolve to type byte[] inarray

Tags: java, android

My code looks like this:

```
private static long ByteLong(byte[] inarray) { 
    int i= 0; 
    inarray[] resultado; 
    resultado = inarray[0];

    for(i = 1; i<=3; i++)
    { 
        resultado = resultado + (inarray[i] * 2 ^ (8 * i)); 
    }

  return resultado; 
}
```

the "inarray[]" at "inarray resultado[]" shows an error in type. why can't it recognize the byte[]??

Comment: You probably meant `byte[] resultado` instead of `inarray[] resultado`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you expect `inarray[] resultado` to mean?

Based on your assignment - `resultado = inarray[0]` - it looks like what you wanted is:

```
byte resultado = inarray[0];
```

or perhaps (based on your return type) :

```
long resultado = inarray[0];
```

Comment: one more thing.. why does this line keeps giving my app unexceptional error?  byte[] payload = record.getPayload();
             String text = new String(payload);
    fromNFC.setText(text); <---This part produces error. NOTE: "fromNFC"is the id of the textview

Comment: @ARYhan What do you mean by `unexceptional error`? Did you fix the line with the invalid syntax?

Comment: @ARYhan Did you initialize the `fromNFC` variable? Perhaps it's still null.

Comment: yes it was declared "TextView fromNFC;" when i remove that line the app is working smoothly, but when i try to put that, it says unfortunately, the app has stopped

Comment: @ARYhan `TextView fromNFC;` is not enough. You have to initialize the value of `fromNFC` before trying to access it.

Answer (score 0):

`inarray[] resultado` is an invalid variable declaration, as `inarray[]` is a **variable**, not an **identifier**.

You probably want to use

```
byte[] resultado;
```